# Using square root in a Matlab title

Tags: matlab

My code will demonstrate the difficulty I am having with latex coding in my title.

```
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,40); 
phi=linspace(0,pi/4,40); 
[theta,phi]=meshgrid(theta,phi); 
rho=3; 
x=rho*sin(phi).*cos(theta); 
y=rho*sin(phi).*sin(theta); z=rho*cos(phi); 
mesh(x,y,z) 
hold on 
r=linspace(0,3*sin(pi/4),40); 
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,40); 
[r,theta]=meshgrid(r,theta); 
x=r.*cos(theta); 
y=r.*sin(theta); 
z=r; 
mesh(x,y,z) 
xlabel('x-axis') 
ylabel('y-axis') 
zlabel('z-axis') 
h=title('Graph of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9$ and $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$',...
    'interpreter','latex',...
    'FontSize',14) 
view(130,20)
```

My Image:

[image]

As you can see, the title is unreadable. I am using version R2013a on a MacBook Pro using the latest version of Mavericks.

How can I make my title readable?

Comment: Does it get better after you exported the matlab figure into a *.eps or *.png (or your preferred format) file?

Comment: it looks ok on windows 7 using 2013a, screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6qpDb.png)  this is a platform specific font issue it seems. try using default font size to see if it helps.

Comment: Does it help to change the figure's `'Renderer'` property?

Comment: The answer to the first comment is "Yes," it does get better when exported to a PDF file. However, when we are doing these during class time, this is a problem and students can't read the title.

Comment: When I changed the figures renderer property to "Painters", it was much nicer. However, when doing their homework, my students use cell mode and then "Publish" their final work. How can the renderer be set before they hit the Publish button and print there work?

Comment: Have you tried export_fig from here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky issue with publish. Firstly Matlab uses figures with most of the properties as default, including the `renderer` property

### The Good News

this can be changed for the current session by running the following line in the command window

```
set(0,'DefaultFigureRenderer','painters')
```

Alternatively it can be added into the publishing options through the publish menu

[image: menu option]

and then adding the line into the the "Matlab expression" box before running the code

[image: block with code]

---

### The Bad News

However this will only achieve so much as publish doesn't allow pdf files to use vector image formats.
From experience text equations in raster images from Matlab are only appear any good with no resizing (luckily non is automatically performed).

The fact they are not supported is not in the help for publish.  The snippet below from publish.m shows that pdf output only supports bmp, jpeg or no images...

```
if strcmp(options.format,'pdf') && ...
        ~isempty(options.imageFormat) && ...
        ~(strcmp(options.imageFormat,'bmp') || strcmp(options.imageFormat,'jpeg'))
    error(pm('InvalidPDFImageFormat'));
end
```

Knowing pdfs can support vector images can we just ignore this?
not simply, it seems this lack of vector support for pdf is due to the underlying java used by Matlab to create pdf files.

A snipet from the error caused by forcing Matlab to publish pdf with a vector image...

```
Reason: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: 
    Cannot load image (no suitable loader/converter combination available)
```

---

**note**: an alternative to setting the default is to set the renderer for each image in the script after setting properties etc by catching the figure handle or using `gcf`
and adding the line `set(gcf,'renderer','painters')`

Comment: Pretty sensational answer. Lots of choices I can explore. Thanks.